# Avoid unnecessary List creation due to - IList<> .ToList()

Tags: c#

I find more code with `.ToList()`, where list operations on an `IList<t>` method call result are required.
So when a method returning `IList<t>` used a List internally as the instance then some form of check prior to using `ToList()` seems appropriate.

The `ToList` extension doesnt seem to check if source is already a List.
See decompile source below.

Is a custom extension to avoid what looks like list duplication a good idea?
eg

```
public  static List<T> ToListWCheck<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
   if (source == null){ return null;}               
   var isListAlready = source as List<T>;
   return isListAlready ?? source.ToList();
}
```

**Is there a better way to handle IList<> to List<> efficiently;?**

```
// Extract from System.Linq.Enumerable

 public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
 {
  if (source == null)
    throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
  else
    return new List<TSource>(source);
}
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.List`1"/> class that contains elements copied from the specified collection and has sufficient capacity to accommodate the number of elements copied.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="collection">The collection whose elements are copied to the new list.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="collection"/> is null.</exception>
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
  if (collection == null)
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.collection);
  ICollection<T> collection1 = collection as ICollection<T>;
  if (collection1 != null)
  {
    int count = collection1.Count;
    if (count == 0)
    {
      this._items = List<T>._emptyArray;
    }
    else
    {
      this._items = new T[count];
      collection1.CopyTo(this._items, 0);
      this._size = count;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    this._size = 0;
    this._items = List<T>._emptyArray;
    foreach (T obj in collection)
      this.Add(obj);
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like this would break the abstraction.  `Enumerable.ToList()` is meant to create a new list from the enumerable source.  Overriding that to *sometimes* create a new list and *sometimes* return a reference to the existing source sounds like it would introduce side-effects.

Comment: Are you sure that real code calls ToList on a List that often? And since Lists are mutable, removing the duplication is not without side effects.

Comment: @David he is not overriding the existing ToList extension, he creates a new one `ToListWCheck` which is fine I guess. (We had this in one bigger project that one very intelligent developer created his own "ToList" on object which wraps whatever comes in into a new list... THIS caused a lot of side effects :p

Comment: @MichaC: In that case I suppose it's fine (I didn't notice the method name, you're right).  Best to advertise very well what it does, of course.

Comment: yes side affects on the original lists are a serious consideration. it could only be used where the original list use was appropriate. And yes overriding ToList() would be very poor idea.;-)

Comment: @PhilSoady In my humble opinion, overriding `ToList` or adding a `ToListWithCheck` are both poor solutions, and the way the `ToList` was used (on a source that is already a list) seems like wrong usage of the method. Adding a method that also checks if the source is already a list is more of a code smell to me. I'd say the comments of David and Henk answer the question better than the answer below

Comment: Have you actually diagnosed an efficiency problem in this particular part of your code? Anyway, asking is something is "a good idea" is too broad or opinion-based.

Comment: @philsoady Maybe you could use that approach and temporarily override `ToList` with a method which loggs all usages where it is already a `List<T>` this way you could identify all sources in your code. Only if it is a very large code base with lot of code where it might not be that easy to figure out if we already have a list. Then refactor the code and remove the overload... Or just have a #IF DEBUG condition to use it only in debug mode... Because the end goal  is to not have such cases in your code, right?

Comment: No Specific efficiency issue no. Although the process happens often. Lists are by habit returned as IList. Still made me wonder if it could be done better

Comment: @David, your response seems the most appropriate answer. Please promote to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn some comments (mine and others) into a viable answer...

If there's a temptation to override `.ToList()` itself, definitely don't do that.  The functionality of `.ToList()` is to enumerate over an enumeration and create an in-memory list of it.  If that enumeration is *already* a list, that shouldn't matter.  Making it matter would break the abstraction of the enumerable.  Not to mention that creating a `.ToList()` method which *sometimes* returns a new list and *sometimes* returns a reference to the original source would *definitely* introduce side-effects.  Subtle, difficult-to-debug side-effects.

In terms of creating a separate method, it's certainly viable but I'd tread carefully.  I agree with the comment posted by @bas that it's more of a code smell than anything else.  If you create such a method on `IList<T>` then it's redundant.  If you create it on `IEnumerable<T>` then you're again creating something which *sometimes* does one thing and *sometimes* does another, which subtly breaks the abstraction.

You *can* create this method, but I'd be very careful about the name and the intellisense documentation of the method.  Advertise *very* clearly what it does.  Method names should never be mis-informative.  But also ask yourself if the potential performance gain outweighs the subtle loss of abstraction and subtle coupling of implementations.  I suspect it does not.  And you wouldn't want to find yourself in a position where the use of this method is littered throughout the codebase only *then* to discover that it's not working out as well as hoped, because reverting all of those uses would in turn also create side-effects and bugs.

Can you do it?  Yes.  Should you?  It's probably not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

For those who might not be aware, [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was added as of .NET 4.5.  I've started using this in place of `IEnumerable<T>` as a return value when I know I'm creating the list once and don't plan to ever change it again.  If you use this consistently along the call chain, you can avoid creating multiple copies of lists all over the place.  It's actually significantly improved performance in one of my applications that does a lot of operations on lists.

For even stronger guarantees, there is an [`ImmutableList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the new Immutable Collections package, which is not strictly part of the framework, but is being released as a sort of official extension by Microsoft.  Between this and the above, I think we'll see a slow move away from using IEnumerable everywhere.  This is a good thing, I think, as it could be difficult to tell previously whether a method used deferred execution, which meant you would very often immediately call ToList() or ToArray(), creating unnecessary copies when the function was already creating and returning a collection internally.

Comment: thanks for that tip, it was exactly these concerns that bothered me with IList<T> / IEnumerable<T>. And given IList<T> supports inserts and remove, the side effects arguments against checking if already List are diluted as the object was immutable in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

I would opt for a slightly different approach to have code more explicit:

```
public static bool TryCast<TEnumerable, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TValue> enumeration, out TEnumerable result) where TEnumerable: IEnumerable<TValue>
{
    result = default(TEnumerable);

    if (enumeration is TEnumerable)
    {
        result = (TEnumerable)enumeration;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

An then in your code:

```
var test = Enumerable.Empty<string>();  
if (!test.TryCast(out IReadOnlyList<string> list))
    list = test.ToArray();
```

Comment: What is the advantage of the `TryCast` over the [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) operator? `​​if (test is IReadOnlyList<string> list)`